# NGRX: how to merge entities from IStore (one-to-many relationship)

Tags: ngrx

I need to merge two `Observable`s. My `IStore` is like:

```
export interface IStore {
  user: IUser;
  plans: IPlanRedux;
  subscriptions: ISubscriptionRedux;
}
```

where `IPlanRedux` is:

```
export interface IPlan {
    id?: string;
    name?: string;
    amount?: number;
    created?: Date;
    currency?: string;
    interval?: string;
    intervalCount?: number;
    trialPeriodDays?: number;
}

export interface IPlanRedux {
    entities: { [key: string]: IPlan };
    ids: Array<string>;
}
```

and `ISubscriptionRedux` is:

```
export interface ISubscription {
    id?: string;
    customer?: string;
    ...
    plan?: string;
    status?: string;
}

export interface ISubscriptionRedux {
    entities: { [key: string]: ISubscription };
    ids: Array<string>;
}
```

As you can see I'm storing plans and subscription separately. I need to join them. I mean, into a component I need to get each subscription of user and for each subscription I need to get the plan of this subscription. So, I'd like to get the subscription adding `currency` and `amount` fields of its plan:

```
{
 id: "from subscription",
 customer: "from subscription",
 plan: "from subscription",
 status: "from subscription",
 amount: "from plan",
 currency: "from plan"
}
```

Currently, on my `ngOnInit` component method I'm getting subscriptions:

```
ngOnInit():void {
  this.store$
    .select(fromRoot.getUserState)
    .filter(user => user.id != null && user.logged)
    .do(user => this.store$.dispatch({type: 'LOAD_SUBSCRIPTIONS', payload: {username: user.username}}))
    .take(1)
    .subscribe();
}
```

So, I don't know:

1. When to dispatch `'LOAD_PLANS'` action.
2. How to merge them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I use the reselect library to solve this problem many times a day.  Not only does it allow you to write readable queries that combine multiple slices of state together to create a view object to your component's liking, it also optimizes queries so that once a query is run against the store.state it will not run it again unless that slice of state has changed.  This makes a difference the bigger your app gets.
 https://github.com/reactjs/reselect